# file upload mvc 4 web application to server without modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hi I need to write a program to store the file path in the database and store the .doc file in a new file location under the same name of the filename . I'm not sure how to write the code for it.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/SaveDoc/"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);   }
        return RedirectToAction("UploadDocument");
    }
}
```

view::

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="FileUpload" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" /> }
```

Comment: Refer [Create Directory Dynamically and Save Image to Folder in](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-directory-dynamically-and-save-image-to-folder-in-asp-net1)

Comment: I'm using Razor engine, I believe .asp will not be supported, could you please help me with alternative way (jqwidgets,boostrap,jquery etc)

Comment: You wrote the program is the basic and correct program to store the file

Comment: What are you facing the problem at?

Comment: It just uploads the file to the location 'SaveDoc' but it doesn't adds the folder in the name of the file. and it doesn't stores the path in database though it stores the file @ Sorangwala Abbasali

Comment: Its obviously not storing the path in DB because you haven't wrote any code to save the path in DB in ActionResult method.

Comment: Could you help me with it? how to write the function to save in my DB? @Sorangwala Abbasali

Comment: What are you using entity framework?

Comment: No. I'm not using entity framework.

Comment: So what are you using as database connection for other things in your project?

Comment: I've configured the db connection in App Setting at Webconfig File. <appSetting >
            <add key="con" value="Server=admin;database=hms;userid=sa;pwd=cyborg"/>
        </asssetting>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your solution and it works with a few adjustments:

1. Make sure the controller in your case is called Upload
2. The name="FileUpload" from the view must match the argument of the method in the controller
3. The submit button does not need to have a value attribute.

I did these changes and everything worked fine.